# number of days remaining in the year in bash

Tags: bash, macos, shell

This kills my linter in vs-code.
Is there a one-liner that could better perform this?

```
echo -n "$((($(date -j -f "%Y%m%d" "$(( $(date +"%Y0101")+10000 ))" "+%s") - $(date "+%s"))/(60*60*24)))";
echo " days until $(( $(date +"%Y")+1 ))"
```

prints:

```
308 days until 2020
```

Comment: ...do you want *clean* code (as implied by "better"), or do you want *terse* code (as implied by "one-liner")?

Comment: (And which version of bash? Very new releases have a `printf %(...)T` builtin that's a much more efficient replacement for `date`, at least for the limited set of operations it supports).

Comment: What version of `date` is this? GNU `date` has no `-j` option, as far as I can tell.

Comment: @BenjaminW. That's the BSD `date`, which is what macOS uses. (And macOS implies `bash` 3.2 with no `%(...)T` support in `printf`.)

Comment: If it is December 31st are there zero days left or one day?

Comment: How about this: `echo $((365 - $(date '+%-j') ))`?

Comment: Is the problem that it's giving the wrong result, or just that VS Code's linter prints warnings about it? What are the warnings?

Comment: @LuisMuñoz wrong on leap years. shorter as `date +365-%-j|bc`

Answer (score 1):

Pure Bash one-liner (tested on Linux, no Mac here)

```
eoy=$([ -n "$(date -d 'Feb 29' '+%-j' 2>/dev/null)" ] && echo 366); echo "$((${eoy:-365} - $(date '+%-j'))) days until $(($(date -d 'Dec 31' '+%Y') +1))"
```

Result:

```
307 days until 2020
```

Testing a leap year:

```
eoy=$([ -z "$(date -d 'Feb 29 2020' '+%-j' 2>/dev/null)" ] && echo 366); echo "$((${eoy:-365} - $(date '+%-j'))) days until $(($(date -d 'Dec 31 2020' '+%Y') +1))"
```

Result:

```
308 days until 2021
```

Same in 2 lines:

```
# year days if leap year
eoy=$([ -z "$(date -d 'Feb 29' '+%-j' 2>/dev/null)" ] && echo 366)
# ${eoy:-365} -> if $eoy is not set or empty string use default 365
echo "$((${eoy:-365} - $(date '+%-j'))) days until $(($(date -d 'Dec 31' '+%Y') +1))"
```

Answer (score 0):

Even if you tagged the question with bash, I would use Python. If you need, you can call Python from within a shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash

python -c '
from datetime import datetime as dt

now = dt.now()
next_year = now.year+1
print(f"{(dt(next_year,1,1)-now).days} days until {next_year}")'
```

Output (using the UTC timezone):

```
306 days until 2020
```

Comment: python3 on ubuntu seems to require surrounding double quotes (rather than single quotes) for the one liner

Comment: Could also use single quotes on the outside and double quotes on the inside, and I'd argue that that's the better choice; single quotes have cleaner parsing rules to the shell, whereas to Python it doesn't matter either way.